# A simple euclidean geometry problem of angles of a triangle using linear equations

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I am having problems solving this problem:

[image]

Using only basic geometry is easy to go here:

[image]

And propose 4 equations:
$$ x+y+70=180$$
$$x+w+40=180 $$
$$u+y+50=180 $$
$$u+w+20=180 $$
And it doesn't make sense to me because, they are linear dependent, we can reduce it to 3 equations that depends (for example) of $u$.Giving us: $$y=130-u$$ $$w=160-u $$ $$x=u-20 $$

But for the construction of the problem, it don't understand how can this problem depends of a variable, and don't know how to solve it. Please help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let in $\Delta ABC$ we have $BA=BC$ and $\measuredangle ABC=20^{\circ}.$

Also, let $M\in BA$ and $N\in BC$ such that $\measuredangle BCM=20^{\circ}$ and $\measuredangle NAB=30^{\circ}.$

We need to find $\measuredangle NMC$ and $\measuredangle MNA$.

Indeed, let $K\in BN$ such that $KM||AC$ and let $AK\cap CM=\{L\}.$

Thus, $\Delta ACL$ and $\Delta KML$ they are equilateral triangles, which gives
$$NC=AC=CL$$ and since $\measuredangle NCL=20^{\circ},$ we obtain $$\measuredangle CNL=\measuredangle NCL=80^{\circ},$$
which gives
$$\measuredangle NLK=\measuredangle NKM-\measuredangle KLM=100^{\circ}-60^{\circ}=40^{\circ}.$$
In another hand,
$$\measuredangle NKL=\measuredangle NKM-\measuredangle LKM=100^{\circ}-60^{\circ}=40^{\circ},$$
which gives $$NK=NL$$ and since $$MK=ML,$$ we obtain that
$$\Delta NKM\cong\Delta NLM,$$ which gives
$$x=\measuredangle NML=\frac{1}{2}\measuredangle KML=\frac{1}{2}\cdot60^{\circ}=30^{\circ}$$ and from here
$$y=110^{\circ}-30^{\circ}=80^{\circ}.$$

Comment: Jmm thanks. I don't know if you could tell me what was wrong with my reasoning please.

Comment: @J.Rodriguez Your reasoning is right, but it does not give a solution of your problem.

Comment: Ok ok, thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome!